# Sound plays in simulator, not device

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have created an app (Xcode 4.6). The app has a sound file that plays when the app opens. The issue I have is that the sound only plays in the simulator, but not on the iPhone when the app is installed. I have checked that the sound works on the phone, it does.

The code complies without any errors or warning.

I have the AVFoundation.framework in my Framework folder.

In my .h file I have:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in the .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"magic-chime-01" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT

I have checked that the file is there, which it is. Also the interesting thing here is I also have Push Notifications running in the app. When a notification is displayed there is no sound. The sound is incorporated in the json file that sent the push notifications.

Comment: Might b the case sensitivity issue. check if file name is exactly the same as "magic-chime-01"(check case sensitive).

Comment: In project navigator:

1. choose your project

2. go to Build Phases

3. check if your audio file is inside "Copy Bundle Resources".